# Split columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

i have this table :

```
id        text
-------   ----------------------------------------------------
128       1|abc def|2|asdfgh|qwerty|3|zxvcb|6/3/2015|2015|
128       1|asd adad|2|djfk|sdsd|3|asadd|7/3/2015|2015|
129       1|adads asad|2|saad|asda|3|asdad|8/3/2015|2015|
```

i want to be like this :

```
id      test_1             test_2                test_3
----    ------------------ --------------------- ------------------
128     1|abc def|         2|asdfgh|qwerty|      3|zxvcb|6/3/2015|2015|
128     1|asd adad|        2|djfk|sdsd|          3|asadd|7/3/2015|2015| 
129     1|adads asad|      2|saad|asda|          3|asdad|8/3/2015|2015|
```

Can any body help me please?

Comment: What is the logic that you're using to split the data?  Does `test_1` always have two pipe-separated sets of values?  Then `test_2` has the next 3 pipe-separated values?  And `test_3` has the next 4?  Or do you break when you see a `1`, a `2`, and a `3`?  Are you guaranteed that every row will break out into three columns?  Or do you want the number of columns to be dynamic?

Comment: Why do you store data like that when you are using a dbms??? Different data in different columns/rows!

Comment: It beats the whole purpose of having a DBMS when you are storing different data in the same column, it just makes data manipulation whole lot tougher.

Comment: `Why do you store data like that when you are using a dbms?` It could be a temp table with imported client data or something like that. It's not uncommon to have to work with data that aren't normalized.

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, substr(text, pos1, pos2-pos1) as text1, substr(text, pos2, pos3-pos2) as text2, substr(text, pos3) as text3 
  from (select id, text, instr(text, '1|') pos1, instr(text, '2|') pos2, instr(text, '3|') pos3    
          from (
        select 128 as id, '1|abc def|2|asdfgh|qwerty|3|zxvcb|6/3/2015|2015|' as text from dual union all
        select 128 as id, '1|asd adad|2|djfk|sdsd|3|asadd|7/3/2015|2015|' as text from dual  union all
        select 129 as id, '1|adads asad|2|saad|asda|3|asdad|8/3/2015|2015|' as text from dual
        )
)
```

Comment: This will fail if the 2nd string happens to end with the digit 2 or 3. e.g. `'1|abc def2|2|asdfgh|qwerty|3|zxvcb|6/3/2015|2015|'`

Comment: @Jeffrey Kemp -  I think you can find another million use-cases when it fails :-) I just give an idea how to solve this problem.